# WebDeploy 3.0 RunCommand executes too soon via WebDeploy agent

Tags: msdeploy, webdeploy

I'm using WebDeploy 3.0 with a manifest file, which contains both a `contentPath` and `runCommand`.

```
<siteManifest>
  <contentPath path="C:\Test\Path" />
  <runCommand path="echo hello" />
</siteManifest>
```

I've come across an issue that the `runCommand` is executing before the `contentPath` provider has synchronised files (only directories) - and only when executed from a remote machine via the agent.

The following is the output when executed via WebDeploy directly:

```
Info: Using ID 'xxx' for connections to the remote server.    
Info: Adding siteManifest (siteManifest).
Info: Adding virtual path (C:\Test\Path)
Info: Adding file (C:\Test\Path\File)
Info: Updating runCommand (echo hello).
Info: hello
Info: The process 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe' (command line '') exited with code '0x0'.
```

The following is the output when executed via the WebDeploy agent:

```
Info: Using ID 'xxx' for connections to the remote server.    
Info: Adding siteManifest (siteManifest).
Info: Adding virtual path (C:\Test\Path)
Info: Updating runCommand (echo hello).
Info: hello
Info: The process 'C:\Windows\system32\cmd.exe' (command line '') exited with code '0x0'.
Info: Using ID 'xxx' for connections to the remote server.
Info: Adding file (C:\Test\Path\File)
```

Any idea how to stop the `RunCommand` happening before `contentPath` when using the WebDeploy agent?

Comment: Can you clarify "web deploy agent"? Do you mean MSDeploy agent service (needs an admin user) or the Web Management Service (msdeploy.axd, no admin user required)? (Also, hey Mike!)

Comment: I do mean the MSDeploy agent service I believe (hey Rich!).

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like it has something do with the commit phase that the remote execution goes through. While I can't offer a direct solution, have you considered moving your runCommand to a [postSync](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd569089%28v=ws.10%29.aspx)?

```
msdeploy -verb:sync ^
         -source:manifest=manifest.xml ^
         -dest:auto,computerName=... ^
         -postSync:runCommand="echo hello"
```

Comment: Thanks Richard :) for various reasons of compatibility we want to keep the command executed via a manifest file, rather than from the command line. It does look like postSync is the only option at the moment.